# Elastic ngram prioritise whole words

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to build an autocomplete with several million possible values.  I have managed to do it with two different methods match and ngram. The problem is that match requires the user to type whole words and ngram returns poor results. Is there a way to only return ngram results if there are no match results?

**Method 1: match**

Returns very relevant results but requires user to type a full word

```
//mapping
analyzer: {
   std_english: {
   type: 'standard',
   stopwords: '_english_',
   },
} 

//search
query: {
   bool: {
   must: [
       { term: { semanticTag: type } }, 
       { match: { search } }
    ]}
}
```

**Method 2: ngram**

Returns poor matches

```
//mapping
analysis: {
  filter: { 
     autocomplete_filter: {
        type: 'edge_ngram',
        min_gram: 1,
        max_gram: 20,
     },
},
analyzer: {
  autocomplete: {
    type: 'custom',
    tokenizer: 'standard',
    filter: ['lowercase', 'autocomplete_filter'],
    },
},


//search
query: {
   bool: {
   must: [
       { term: { semanticTag: type } }, 
       { match: {
          term: { 
             query: search,
             operator: 'and',
             }
          }
        }
    ]}
}
```

Comment: it would not be possible to do in a single call, but you can have a look at https://opster.com/elasticsearch-glossary/elasticsearch-autocomplete-troubleshooting-guide/ to optimize this further and let me know if you need further info and optimization

Answer (score 0):

Try changing query to something like this -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "semanticTag": "type"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "fieldName": {
              "query": "valueToSearch"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can use `match_phrase_prefix`, by using this user will not need to type the whole word, anything that user types and which starts with indexed field data will get returned.
Just a note that this will also pull results from any available middle words from indexed documents as well. 
For e.g. If data indexed in one of field is like - `"lorem ipsum"` and user type `"ips"` then you will get this whole document along with other documents that starts with `"ips"` 
You can go with either standard or custom analyzer, you have to check which analyzer better suits your use case. According to information available in question, given above approach works well with `standard analyzer`.